# Les descriptions de « canot » et de « chaloupe » au Québec sont-elles interchangées en France?

Tags: sens, québec, comparaison-de-langues, définition

Au Québec:

> Canot: embarcation pointue aux deux extrémités (symétrique).

> Chaloupe: embarcation avec tableau arrière.

Selon *Wikipédia* en français:

« La coque de la chaloupe est souvent pointue aux deux extrémités, ce qui la distingue du canot qui a un tableau arrière. »

N’hésitez pas à apporter une modification au titre de la question au besoin; j’ignore en fait et en toute franchise s’il est formulé avec les termes appropriés à l’idée que je veux exprimer. - Interchangé, interverti, inversé ou autre???! -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je ne crois pas que la symétrie proue/poupe soit ce qui caractérise une **chaloupe** ou un **canot** en France.

Pour moi, un canot est simplement plus petit qu'une chaloupe, les deux peuvent avoir un tableau arrière ou être symétriques proue/poupe.

J'ai aussi lu qu'on appelait **canot** au Québec ce qu'on appelle **canoë** en France, c'est peut-être ce qui motive ta question car un canoë est toujours symétrique.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Ah, on n'appellerait pas ça une chaloupe mais une barque.

Comment: La nuance est interminable, Notre [chaloupe](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/10880251/chaloupe) est une barque ou un canot, notre [canot](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/2079485/canot) est un canoë, voire canadien, et notre [canoë](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/2068321/canoe) est un... canoë qui est quasiment comme un kayak. On les embarque tous, on prend facilement une débarque avec tout ce qui n'est pas une chaloupe... trouvez l'erreur !

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Ah, un kayak n'est jamais un canoë pour nous.